# Exibindo GridView Mestre Detalhe de forma que os detalhes sejam mostrados em baixo de cada mestre

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-3, gridview

Utilizo o controle GridView do ASP.NET para exibir as informações de duas tabelas que tem uma relação mestre-detalhe. Tabela1: Compra (IDCompra, DataCompra e ValorCompra) e Tabela 2: CompraItem (IDCompraItem, Nome, Quantidade).

Gostaria de exibir uma página de lista mais ou menos dessa maneira:

1 - 03/04/2016 - R$100,00

- 4 - Caneta - 20 unidades
- 6 - Lápis - 10 unidades
- 7 - Borracha - 5 unidades

2 - 03/04/2016 - R$ 50,00

- 9 - apontador - 3 unidades
- 10 - Lápis - 2 unidades

3 - 04/04/2016 - R$ 5,00

- 15 - Papel - 3 caixas

Eu Conseguiria fazer isso com bootstrap? Como? Existe outra maneira?

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada no link abaixo, é um pouco diferente pois ele só mostra se você expandir:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx

O que ele faz é criar uma GridView (table) e criar dentro dela um template field com outra GridView. Nesse código usa-se javascript para mostrar e esconder a subGrid.